# How to change strings in dataframe to date time values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a pandas dataframe of strings representing dates in the form

```
 Year-day hour:minute:second.microsecond
```

Except the day is written as a single number from 0-364. For example, the date`2019-040 04:00:00:000000` represents 4 am on february 9, 2019. How do I convert these values to date time instances?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datetime` and `strptime` to achieve this. The `%j` [directive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) allows you to enter the zero-padded day number of the year:

```py
import datetime as dt
date_time = '2019-040 04:00:00:000000'
dt.datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%j %H:%M:%S:%f')
```

Output:

```py
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 9, 4, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are really asking is, what is the directive of days of the year padded with 0. It's "%j".

So in this case you would do %Y for year, %j for day, %H for hour, %M for minute, %S for seconds, %f for microseconds.

```
pd.to_datetime(column, format='%Y-%j %H:%M:%S:%f')
```